# Scrolling attribute doesn't work for iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/idennis/x0pcdk6n/)

html:

```
<iframe id="frame" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

js:

```
frame.contentWindow.document.write('scroll</br><div style="width:100px;height:100px;"><canvas id="cv"></canvas></div>');
var cv = frame.contentWindow.document.body.childNodes[2].childNodes[0];
var context = cv.getContext("2d");
cv.height = cv.width = 500;
context.fillStyle = "red";
context.rect(0, 0, 500, 500);
context.fill();
```

Why doesn't this work on android 4.2 (maybe in others)? Why i can scroll an iframe when scrolling="no"?
Without canvas all works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the  `scrolling="no"` attribute for iFrame was removed from HTML5.
That said, the only real and trustable way to avoid scrolling in iFrame is building a content large, at the most, as the iFrame itself.

My experience says that, even if checking result on as many browsers as possible, it would be always a configuration that shows scrollbars anyway....